# How to get any ControlFlow value?

Tags: rust

Using [`ControlFlow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.ControlFlow.html) in [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) seems better than `Option` in this case where one need to use any value.

But it's not very pleasant to use `ControlFlow` in `try_fold` because this irrefutable pattern shown below:

```rust
    let (Break(value) | Continue(value)) =
        values
            .iter()
            .try_fold(0, |previous, &current| match (previous) {
                0 => Continue(1),
                1 => Continue(2),
                _ => Break(3),
            });
```

Is there a way to get rid of this irrefutable pattern while using `ControlFlow` and retrieving the value?

Comment: I don't understand what isn't pleasant with this code.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I would like to know if there is a more idiomatic way to do that.

Comment: `c @ 0 | 1 => Continue(c)`?

Comment: If you're talking about the `let`, I don't see a method to condense a `ControlFlow<T, T>` into a `T`, perhaps once could be proposed (similar to [`into_ok_or_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.into_ok_or_err) for `Result<T, T>`).

Comment: @kmdreko `into_ok_or_err()` was actually removed, but it is more likely for a similar method to exist in `ControlFlow` since the removal reason was that error and success values should not be unified.

Comment: Yeh, having something like `into_ok_or_err()` for `ControlFlow` would be useful. Thanks everyone for trying.

Comment: @mdmundo did you end up opening an issue for this? I've tried using `ControlFlow` and have also been disappointed by the lack of a "unification" path as early-returning the reduction state would be a big use case for using `try_fold`, but the extra work necessary to get the final value out makes it a lot less nice.

Comment: Actually there is [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/75744#issuecomment-1345267376) in the tracking issue for `ControlFlow`. @Masklinn